# How can I create a generic elastic beanstalk module?

Tags: terraform

I'm trying to create a reusable terraform module for an elastic beanstalk resource. I'm stuck trying to figure out how I can pass in application environment variables. I'd like to do something like this:

./api.tf

```
module "eb" {
  source = "./eb"

  name    = "api"
  vpc_id  = "${var.vpc_id}"
  ...

  environment = {
    VAR1  = "${var.var1}"
    VAR2  = "${var.var2}"
    VAR3  = "${var.var3}"
    ...
  }  
}
```

./eb/eb.tf

```
variable "name"         { }
variable "vpc_id"       { }
variable "environment"  { type = "map" }

resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment" "api" {
  name  = "${var.name}"
  ...

  setting {
    namespace   = "aws:ec2:vpc"
    name        = "VPCId"
    value       = "${var.vpc_id}"
  }

  # application environment variables

  # Here's where I'm stuck:
  # I would like to iterate over the environment map, setting name and value.
  setting {
    count       = "${length(keys(var.environment))}"
    namespace   = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment"
    name        = "${element(keys(var.environment), count.index)}"
    value       = "${lookup(var.environment, element(keys(var.environment), count.index))}"
  }
}
```

My first problem is it doesn't look like count is supported on options. Are there other ways to accomplish something similar so I can provide additional settings to the eb module?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution based on this answer: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/12294#issuecomment-323235796

You can use a variable of type "list" in Terraform to specify a list of maps.

This worked for me:

```
provider aws {
  region = "us-east-1"
}

variable environment_variables {
  type = "list"
  default = [
    {
      namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment"
      name = "VAR1"
      value = "Value1"
    },
    {
      namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment"
      name = "VAR2"
      value = "Value2"
    }
  ]
}

resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_application" "app" {
  name = "temp-example-app"
}

resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment" "app" {
  name = "temp-example-app"
  application = "${aws_elastic_beanstalk_application.app.id}"
  solution_stack_name = "64bit Amazon Linux 2017.03 v2.6.0 running Docker 1.12.6"

  setting = ["${var.environment_variables}"]

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration"
    name = "InstanceType"
    value = "t2.micro"
  }
  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment"
    name = "EnvironmentType"
    value = "SingleInstance"
  }
}
```

Note: I didn't specify an app version so you may get errors on apply but you should be able see the environment variables in the AWS Console.

Comment: Nice! I didn't know you could pass in a list to the setting option for default variables like that. Thanks

Comment: This is clever but it only works if you have at least 1 environment variable.  if you don't have any it breaks.